# Nested layout weight

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to design my UI like this:
[image]

The problem is when I add ListView and set its width to match_parent, it uses the root layout and takes width of the whole screen even though it is wrapped in another layout, that takes just 1/4 of the width. Could somebody suggest me a way how to accomplish whats drawn on the picture? I also read that nested layout_weight is bad for performance, should I use something completely different?

XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"> 
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="13">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your right-hand view to be a `RelativeLayout`, setting your button to be at the bottom of your right hand view and then setting the property  `android:layout_above="@id/button1"` on your `ListView` will allow you to have your `ListView` fill the remaining space that your button doesn't occupy. I also removed lots of unneeded nested layouts you had.

Don't forget that when using layout weights you need to specify 0dip for the width/height depending on the orientation of the `LinearLayout`. This is likely why your ListView was occupying the whole screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/button1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have too many `ViewGroup`s for what few `View`s you have. You can probably change this part

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="13">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

to something like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I don't think that extra `LinearLayout` is needed. You also could change this `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` if you need certain properties for your `Button` such as `layout_alignParentBottom` or `layout_above`